# sonarqube version 9.9/10.3 and elastisreach with postgresql 12.6 on Ubuntu 22 - elastic search exits exit value [ElasticSearch]: 78

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, sonarqube

I installed SonarQube  on ubuntu  linux (ubuntu 20)

Presently I am using SonarQube version 9.9.3
(earlier I installed  SonarQube 10.3.0.82913  had same problem so I went one version back and  installed 9.9.3.79811)

The problem persists even after going back to 9.9.3

I am using openjdk 17.0.8.1 2023-08-24 and  PostgreSQL 12.16 (Ubuntu 12.16-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)

The steps that I followed are as below

1. Stood up a Ubuntu linux version 20.2 server and created a linux user called "sonaruser"
2. Installed openjdk 17.0.8.1 2023-08-24 using apt
3. Installed PostgreSQL 12.16 using apt
4. Downloaded the SONAR zip file sonarqube-9.9.3.79811 and unzipped it in a path /opt/sonarqube-9.9.3.79811
5. Changed ownership of /opt/sonarqube-9.9.3.79811 and al its sub contents to "sonaruser"
6. Run a set of following database commands through PSQL db superuser

   ````
   CREATE DATABASE sonardb;
   CREATE USER sonaruser with password 'sonarpass';
   ALTER USER sonaruser SET search_path to sonarschema;
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES  ON DATABASE sonardb TO sonaruser```
   ````
7. Log into linux as linux user sonaruser and then log in to postgres  as sonaruser; thereafter run folliwing commands

   `USE sonardb; CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS sonarschema;`
8. Change the configuration in the file opt/sonarqube-9.9.3.79811/conf/sonar.properties as follows

   ````
   sonar.jdbc.username=sonaruser
   sonar.jdbc.password=sonarpass
   sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sonardb? 
   currentSchema=sonarschema
   sonar.web.host=0.0.0.0
   sonar.web.context=/sonarqube
   sonar.web.port=9000 ```
   ````
9. With all of the above done I start sonarqube by running command

   `/opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh`

This however consistantly gives me error in the log as follows

````
```[o.a.h.i.n.c.MainClientExec] [exchange: 1] start execution
2023.11.22 13:56:20 DEBUG app[][o.a.h.c.p.RequestAddCookies] CookieSpec 
selected: default
2023.11.22 13:56:20 DEBUG app[][o.a.h.c.p.RequestAuthCache] Re-using 
cached 'basic' auth scheme for http://127.0.0.1:9001
2023.11.22 13:56:20 DEBUG app[][o.a.h.c.p.RequestAuthCache] No 
credentials for preemptive authentication
2023.11.22 13:56:20 DEBUG app[][o.a.h.i.n.c.InternalHttpAsyncClient] 
[exchange: 1] Request connection for {}->http://127.0.0.1:9001
2023.11.22 13:56:20 DEBUG app[] 
[o.a.h.i.n.c.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection request: 
[route: {}->http://127.0.0.1:9001][total kept alive: 0; route 
allocated: 0 of 10; total allocated: 0 of 30]
2023.11.22 13:56:20 DEBUG app[] 
[o.a.h.i.n.c.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection request 
failed
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:946)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvent(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:174)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:148)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:351)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:221)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
...
2023.11.22 13:56:20 DEBUG app[][o.e.c.RestClient] added [[host=http://127.0.0.1:9001]] to blacklist
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvent(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:174)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:148)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:351)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:221)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
...
2023.11.22 13:56:20 DEBUG app[][o.e.c.RestClient] added 
[[host=http://127.0.0.1:9001]] to blacklist 
...
...
2023.12.01 10:34:36 DEBUG app[][o.e.c.RestClient] updated 
[[host=http://127.0.0.1:9001]] already in blacklist
2023.12.01 10:34:36 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] 
Process exited with exit value [ElasticSearch]: 78```
````

The interesting part is that when I remove the JDBC configuration and
let SONARQUBE start with embedded database then these erros go away and SOnarQube starts fine

I did ascertain that there are no issues with wither port 9000 or 9001 in use before sonarqube is started
And I also ensure that firewalls are turned off

I did check using netcat and telnet that ports 9000 and ports 9001 are free and a server can listen on them and a client on localhost can connect

I changed log level to debug for the elasticsearch as well .   I see in the /opt/sonarqube/log/nohup.log as shown below - this denotes that elastic search is able to bind to port 9001 successfully and Sonarqube connected to it as well . However in the same log - it shows "connection request failed" after some time

```
enter code here
2023.12.01 09:16:34 DEBUG app[][o.s.a.NodeLifecycle] main 
tryToMoveTo from INIT to STARTING => true
2023.12.01 09:16:34 DEBUG app[][o.s.a.p.ManagedProcessLifecycle] 
main tryToMoveTo ElasticSearch from INIT to STARTING => true
2023.12.01 09:16:34 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch 
listening on [HTTP: 127.0.0.1:9001, TCP: 127.0.0.1:38141]
2023.12.01 09:16:34 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch 
process[ELASTICSEARCH] from [/opt/sonarqube- 
9.9.3.79811/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonarqube- 
9.9.3.79811/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
2023.12.01 09:16:34 DEBUG app[][o.s.a.p.ManagedProcessLifecycle] 
main tryToMoveTo ElasticSearch from STARTING to STARTED => true
2023.12.01 09:16:34 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for 
Elasticsearch to be up and running
2023.12.01 09:16:34 DEBUG app[][o.s.a.e.EsConnectorImpl] Connected 
to Elasticsearch node: [127.0.0.1:9001]
.... 
....
....
2023.12.01 09:16:34 DEBUG app[][o.a.h.i.n.c.MainClientExec] 
[exchange: 1] start execution
2023.12.01 09:16:34 DEBUG app[][o.a.h.c.p.RequestAddCookies] 
CookieSpec selected: default
2023.12.01 09:16:34 DEBUG app[][o.a.h.c.p.RequestAuthCache] Re- 
using cached 'basic' auth scheme for http://127.0.0.1:9001
2023.12.01 09:16:34 DEBUG app[][o.a.h.c.p.RequestAuthCache] No 
credentials for preemptive authentication
2023.12.01 09:16:34 DEBUG app[] 
[o.a.h.i.n.c.InternalHttpAsyncClient] [exchange: 1] Request 
connection for {}->http://127.0.0.1:9001
2023.12.01 09:16:34 DEBUG app[] 
[o.a.h.i.n.c.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection 
request: [route: {}->http://127.0.0.1:9001][total kept alive: 0; 
route allocated: 0 of 10; total allocated: 0 of 30]
2023.12.01 09:16:34 DEBUG app[] 
[o.a.h.i.n.c.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection 
request failed
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
....

[o.a.h.i.n.c.InternalHttpAsyncClient] [exchange: 1] connection request failed
2023.12.01 09:16:34 DEBUG app[][o.e.c.RestClient] request [GET http://127.0.0.1:9001/] failed
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
        at
```

And finally this results in same connection error as cited before

IMO the problem is because elastic search starts and then exits

What am I doing wrong that Sonarqube does not start with postgresql JDBC configuration done ?

Your pointers / inputs are sincerely appreciated

Yogesh

Comment: 'Connection refused' means the port 9001 is not actually open and it should be open since elasicsearch use it.  There must be other errors before this output.

Comment: Hi –  @andreypc - I have debug on and log prior to this does not indicate any error/fails

Comment: And @andreypc I can create a listener on the server using netcat on both ports 9000 and 9001 .. and connect to it using telnet - so there isnt any problem with unavailable ports or firewalls

Comment: 'IMO the problem is because elastic search starts and then exits' - thats what I meant when I told there must be some errors prior to one you posted. Thats an abnormal behavior of elasic and it sould be diagnosed at the first place. Not the consequences of it. Have you configured max threads and open files parameters on your linux according to sonarqube installation requirements guide?

Comment: Yes indeed the problem was attributed to elasticsearch - Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

The problem was indeed in elasticsearch.

I referred to this https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/issues/282

And also to

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/vm-max-map-count.html

Elasticsearch uses a mmapfs directory by default to store its indices. The default operating system limit on mmap counts was too low and that was causing elasticsearch to exit

I  set  vm.max_map_count to a value 262144 and then elasticsearch plus sonarqube started working

To set vm.max_map_count in runtime run command

```
 "sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144"
```

To set this value permanently (surviving reboot), update the vm.max_map_count setting in /etc/sysctl.conf.
To verify after rebooting run

`sysctl vm.max_map_count`

And as suggested by @andreypc in comment above, there are other parameters such as  max threads and open files parameters. It might be a good idea to carefully look at snarqube install guide right upfront